# How can we merge key value of dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dictionary

```
[{'a': 'tc1', 'b': 'tc2'}, {'a': 'tc1', 'b': 'tc3'}]
```

I want to create resultant dictionary

```
result = {'tc1':['tc2', 'tc3']}
```

Any idea how we can do that?

```
js = [{'a': 'tc1', 'b': 'tc2'}, {'a': 'tc1', 'b': 'tc3'}]
ls =[]
for i in js:
     x[i['a']]= ls+[(i["b"])]
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: and what result should be obtained from such input list: `[{'a': 'tc1', 'b': 'tc2'}, {'a': 'tc1', 'b': 'tc3'},{'a': 'tc3', 'b': 'tc1'}]` ?

Comment: for i in js:
     x[i['a']]= [(i["b"])]    @jonrsharpe i did something like this but it's not working where js=[{'a': 'tc1', 'b': 'tc2'}, {'a': 'tc1', 'b': 'tc3'}]

Comment: Then [edit] to give a [mcve] and clarify the issue with your current implementation. At a glance, it *replaces* the list for each new value for a key.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Please check complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, the 'a' element will always be the key for the new dictionary, and the 'b' element, its value. Then the following code should work for you:

```
js = [{'a': 'tc1', 'b': 'tc2'}, {'a': 'tc1', 'b': 'tc3'}]
result = {}  # Create the empty result dictionary
for i in js:
    k, v = i['a'], i['b']  # k will be the key, v will be the value
    if k not in result:  # If k is not a key of result yet, we create the entry as an empty list
        result[k] = []
    # By now, we know that k is a key in result. Now we add the value.
    result[k].append(v)
print result # {'tc1': ['tc2', 'tc3']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use reduce from functools:

```
lst = [{'a': 'tc1', 'b': 'tc2'}, {'a': 'tc1', 'b': 'tc3'}]
from functools import reduce
m = reduce(lambda m,kv: m.setdefault(kv[0],[]).append(kv[1]) or m, (kv for d in lst for kv in d.items()), dict() )
print(m) # {'a': ['tc1', 'tc1'], 'b': ['tc2', 'tc3']}
```

which translate to the following procedural code:

```
m = dict()
for d in lst:
    for k,v in d.items():
        m.setdefault(k,[]).append(v)
```